# Getting total pv created for all of User's Django

Tags: django

I have a simple models:

```
class Pv(models.Model):
   accounts =(
      ('Sub CF','Sub CF'),
      ('Special','Special'),
      ('Directors','Directors'),
      ('Operations','Operations'),
      ('LSGDP','LSGDP'),
      ('DWAP','DWAP'),
      ('Capacity(USD)','Capacity(USD)')
            )
   acc =(
      ('Yes','Yes'),
      ('No', 'No')
        )

   source =(
        ('GOG','GOG'),
        ('Others', 'Others')
      )
   pv =(
         ('General','General'),
         ('Honorarium','Honorarium')
       )
  center=(
    ('Cost Center 1','Cost Center 1'),
    ('Cost Center 2','Cost Center 2'),
    ('Cost Center 3','Cost Center 3'),
    ('Cost Center 4','Cost Center 4'),
    ('Cost Center 5','Cost Center 5')
       )
  stat =(
    ('Completed','Completed'),
    ('Returned','Returned'),
    ('Cancelled','Cancelled')
    )
IA_System_Code = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
IA_code = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
Date_recieved = models.DateField()
Pv_reference = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 120)
Source_of_Funding = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = source)
Cost_center = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = center)
Payee = models.CharField(max_length=500)
Description = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
Account_code = models.CharField(max_length=350)
Gross_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
Withholding_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
Net_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
Status = models.CharField(max_length = 60, choices = stat )
Remarks =models.CharField(max_length = 500, blank = True)
Acc_Impress = models.CharField(max_length = 350,choices=acc)
Date_returned =models.DateField(null=True,blank = True)
Type_of_accounts= models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = accounts)
Type_of_pv = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = pv)
returned_to_chest = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True,\ 
                               null=True,\default=None,\
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,\
                               related_name='create')
modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
modified_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True,\ 
                                null=True,default=None\ 
                                ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,\
                                related_name='modified') 
class Meta():
        ordering = ["IA_System_Code"]



def __str__(self):
    return self.Description

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = get_current_user()
    if user and not user.pk:
        user = None
    if not self.pk:
        self.created_by = user
        self.created = datetime.now()
    else:
        self.modified_by = user
        self.modified = datetime.now()
    super(Pv, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm struggling to figure out, what I think should be a simple query, with Django's ORM.

Let's say I have a total of 6 PV created by 3 unique Users
Now, what I really want is to query all pv and count  the pvs created by each User, but only want one of each unique User and add a (what I think should be an annotated) property called total to each User.

So if the User has 2 PV created , his total will be 2.
please can anybody help me out .

here is my query

```
object_list = User.objects.filter(~Q(create = None))\
              .annotate(total=('create__IA_System_Code').count()))`
```

and how do i display it on my template.
please can anyone help me out . looks like i dont know what am doing. thank u

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
object_list = User.objects.filter(create__isnull=False).annotate(total=Count('create__IA_System_Code', distinct=True))
```

As a comment, your code is hard to read because you haven't followed Python or Django conventions. Please checkout out the PEP8 standard and/or the Black formatter (https://github.com/psf/black)

Comment: i get this error    **Cannot resolve keyword 'total' into field. Choices are: Acc_Impress, Account_code, Cost_center, Date_recieved, Date_returned, Description, Gross_amount, IA_System_Code, IA_code, Net_amount, Payee, Pv_reference, Remarks, Source_of_Funding, Status, Type_of_accounts, Type_of_pv, Withholding_tax, created, created_by, created_by_id, modified, modified_by, modified_by_id, returned_to_chest**

Comment: That looks like the list of fields on your `Pv` model. Are you trying to access your `total` field on a User instance or a Pv instance? The annotation is on the User queryset.